# How to derive the group velocity in a dispersive medium and how to interpret it in momentum space?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, velocity, dispersion

I had this homework where I was supposed to derive the [group velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity) of a given wave packet
$$\psi (x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty}dk\,g(k)e^{i(\omega t-kx)}$$
where $$g(k)=e^{-\alpha(k-k_0)^2}$$
and assuming the angular frequency was given by its second order Taylor expansion
$$\omega(k)\approx\omega_0+(k-k_0)\left(\frac{d\omega}{dk}\right)_{k=k_0}+\frac{1}{2}(k-k_0)^2\left(\frac{d^2\omega}{dk^2}\right)_{k=k_0}$$
I did the following:

[image: resolution]

The factor of 2 really bothers me and I cannot understand what I did wrong along the way. Besides this, I'm having a hard time trying to interpret the physical meaning of velocity group in the momentum space. In the $x$ space, I know that the group velocity is the velocity of the wave packet maximum and that the dispersive factor will be responsible for an increase in the width of the wave packet, but in the momentum space, I don't understand what is happening.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to insert equations, variables, etc. Pictures are not accessible to all users.